# What do i do to fix this dual boot ?error: out of disc grub rescue>

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, 10.04, dual-boot

I just instaled ubuntu 10.04 to my old computer that has windows xp sp3 and a new hardrive.at the end it said it need to reboot and when it did i got this.
error: out of disc
grub rescue>
How do i fix this?When i partitioned the drive i gave it 79gigs.I set all the settings as told.Any ideas?Im a first time linux user and if told to type code please type it exactly as it should be typed as i dont know how to type that stuff much.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when GRUB finds no usable config file. Try [restoring GRUB using the Live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal).